# Scale only "bottoms" of a collection of meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a collection of separate meshes (bandages). Is there a way to make all of the "bottoms" (blue color) thicker, while leaving all "tops" (red color) intact? I could obviously do it all manually, but I have 5 more areas like this one and was hoping for some automation.[image]